# Mongodb Aggregation append a field from a collection to every document in an array in another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections like (see below) and I'd like to append only the supplier name to every document inside the product array.  The supplier name is stored in the second collection and can be linked by the supplierId in the product array.

```
order
{
    _id: objectId  // objectId
    product: [{
               sku: 123,
               supplierId: 123,  // objectId
               qty: 10
             },
             {
               sku: 123456,
               supplierId: 1234,
               qty: 5
             }]
     }
}

supplier
{ 
  _id: 1234,   // objectId
  name: "Supplier 1"
},
{
 _id: 123,
 name: "Supplier 2"
}
```

Desired output being something like the below

```
{
    _id: objectId  // objectId
    product: [{
               sku: 123,
               supplierId: 123,  // objectId
               qty: 10,
               name: Supplier 2
             },
             {
               sku: 123456,
               supplierId: 1234,  // objectId
               qty: 5,
               name: Supplier 1
             }]
     }
}
```

My attempt looks something like this which results in two seperate documents with the correct supplier against the correct product.  Not sure if i'm heading in the right direction or where to go next.  Is it a case of some grouping or project step next?  Please advise

```
[{ $unwind: {  path: '$product'} }, 
 { $lookup: {  from: 'supplier',  localField: 'product.supplierId', foreignField: '_id',  as: 'sup'} }
, { $unwind: {  path: '$sup'} }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to add the name to the product from supplier document followed by [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to collect product back into array.

```
db.order.aggregate([
 {"$unwind":"$product"},
 {"$lookup":{"from":"supplier","localField":"product.supplierId","foreignField":"_id","as":"supplier"}},
 {"$unwind":"$supplier"},
 {"$addFields":{"product.name":"$supplier.name"}},
 {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","product":{"$push":"$product"}}}
]
```

Comment: excellent thanks.  Sorry one thing i forgot to mention. i have some other fields in the root of the docuemnt, eg. _id, dateTime, etc.  how can i make sure i still output these too?

Comment: Np. You have to list each of them in the group stage using $first. Something like `dateTime:{$first:"$dateTime"}`.